# How to create a CSV file inside a Azure repo using python

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I'm using azure devops for the first time, just trying to create a CSV file using python script.

Python script main.py:

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# list of name, degree, score
nme = ["aparna", "pankaj", "sudhir", "Geeku"]
deg = ["MBA", "BCA", "M.Tech", "MBA"]
scr = [90, 40, 80, 98]

# dictionary of lists
dict = {'name': nme, 'degree': deg, 'score': scr}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

print(df)

# saving the dataframe
df.to_csv('file.csv', header=False, index=False)

print("CSV file created")
```

Output:

[image]

and it created a csv file in that folder

[image]

What i did is, just went to the repo and created a new repo called myTest and uploaded the python file to there
[image: myTestRepo]
[image]

then went to the pipelines and selected "Azure repos git"->selected "myTest"->"Python Package"-> and edited the YAML file and gave "save and run"
[image]

[image]

[image]

azure-pipelines.yml file content:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python37:
      python.version: '3.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install pandas
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
    python main.py
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

The pipeline ran successfully, but i didn't see any csv file created on the repo
[image]

[image]

Can somebody help me to solve this issue, is it possible to create a csv file inside a azure repo?

Comment: it's created in the agent, not in the repo...

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk how can I access it?

Comment: Is it Microsoft agent or self hosted?

Comment: i think its Microsoft-hosted agent. its showing "Pool: Azure Pipelines, Image: ubuntu-latest, Agent: Hosted Agent"

Comment: So you need to add a step of commit & push to your repo.